# DB QUERY TO DELETE RECORDS

Tags: oracle

I would like to delte records from a table in oracle keeping the last 3 months data into the table and delete the remaining records.

For eg:Now March Keep last 3 months (March,Feb,Jan).Delete from Dec onwards.

Comment: Could you please provide table structure? Also could you please provide your variant of `DELETE` query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "the last 3 months" mean what it says, then subtract 3 months from SYSDATE and you'll have it.

```
delete from your_table
where date_column < add_months(trunc(sysdate), -3);
```

On the other hand, you might investigate some other options (presented by VALx) in the following query, and use one of these in the WHERE clause. I've intentionally done it step-by-step, so that you could see what's the result of each of these options.

From what I think you meant while writing the question, VAL5 might be what you're really looking for.

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi';

Session altered.

SQL> select
  2    sysdate val1,
  3    trunc(sysdate) val2,
  4    add_months(trunc(sysdate), -3) val3,
  5    last_day(add_months(trunc(sysdate), -3)) val4,
  6    last_day(add_months(trunc(sysdate), -3)) + 1 val5
  7  from dual;

VAL1             VAL2             VAL3             VAL4             VAL5
---------------- ---------------- ---------------- ---------------- ----------------
26.03.2018 07:55 26.03.2018 00:00 26.12.2017 00:00 31.12.2017 00:00 01.01.2018 00:00

SQL>
```

Comment: The Query resolved thanks for the kind support